# How to correctly declare an array property in Delphi?

Tags: arrays, delphi

I'm trying to create an array to store every item of a TStringList into an array which size may vary depending on the quantity of items in said TStringList.

I know my syntax is wrong and what I want is probably a dynamic array, so the [0..100] is probably wrong aswell but I could not find any alternative syntax online.

```
ProductAvailabilityResult = Class(TRemotable)
private
  FResultArray : array[1..100] of string;
published
  property ResultArray[Index: Integer]: array of string read FResultArray write FResultArray;
End;
```

And this is how I would invoke it and populate it. **conditionList** being my **TStringList** which I would populate into my array.

```
for I := 0 to conditionList.Count - 1 do
begin
  aProductAvailabilityResult.ResultArray[I] := conditionList[I];
end;
```

In case you may or may not have alternative suggestions to what i'm doing, the reason for this setup is because it's a web service app sending results over a SOAP server, and I don't think my PHP/Soap client can read TStringLists, so I need to pass it to an array first.

Let me know, Thanks!

Comment: The entire question hinges on the remoting, and how that is to be achieved. Why is your code so poorly indented?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  I'm confused, the question does not hinge on remoting by any means. I want to know how I can declare a generic dynamic array which my for loop will populate with the contexts of a TStringList. I can handle the array just fine remotely. Also the indenting issue comes from copy & pasting. It screws up the alignments, so I have to manually space to get the code block on stackoverflow.

Comment: If you want a dynamic array, declare a dynamic array. But you don't have a dynamic array at the moment. You have an array property. Different altogether. You said "I don't think my PHP/Soap client can read TStringLists". So presumably it matters what it can read. Supposed I show you how to create a dynamic array property. Will you promise not to complain if your PHP/Soap client cannot read it?

Comment: Use CTRL+K to format blocks here. The edit window has extensive help. Avail yourself of it. Well presented questions are more attractive to us.

Comment: I want a dynamic array property, how do I acheive that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared an [array property](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties_(Delphi)#Array_Properties), albeit with some syntax errors.  However, you state in the question and comments that you want a property that is a dynamic array. That's different from an array property.

Declare a dynamic array property like so:

```
type
  ProductAvailabilityResult = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FResultArray: TArray<string>;
  published
    property ResultArray: TArray<string> read FResultArray write FResultArray;
  end;
```

Populate it like this:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  List: TStringList;
  par: ProductAvailabilityResult;
  arr: TArray<string>;
....
List := ...;
par := ...;
SetLength(arr, List.Count);
for i := 0 to List.Count-1 do
  arr[i] := List[i];
par.ResultArray := arr;
```

Comment: Thanks this did the trick, sorry for not exactly knowing the in and out of etiquette. I realize this site more than your typical forum has stricter guidelines and a method of workflow that people asking/answering questions are used to. I'm not a power user of SO yet so you'll excuse my poorly formulated question. Thanks again

Answer (score 6):

Your syntax for declaring an array property is close, but you need to use getter/setter methods instead of direct field access, and array properties cannot be declared as `published`:

```
type
  ProductAvailabilityResult = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FResultArray : array of string;
    function GetResultArray(Index: Integer): string;
    function GetResultArrayCount: Integer;
    procedure SetResultArray(Index: Integer; const Value: string);
    procedure SetResultArrayCount(Value: Integer);
  public
    property ResultArray[Index: Integer]: string read GetResultArray write SetResultArray default;
    property ResultArrayCount: Integer read GetResultArrayCount write SetResultArrayCount;
  end;

function ProductAvailabilityResult.GetResultArray(Index: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := FResultArray[Index];
end;

function ProductAvailabilityResult.GetResultArrayCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := Length(FResultArray);
end;

procedure ProductAvailabilityResult.SetResultArray(Index: Integer; const Value: string);
begin
  FResultArray[Index] := Value;
end;

procedure ProductAvailabilityResult.SetResultArrayCount(Value: Integer);
begin
  SetLength(FResultArray, Value);
end;
```

Then you can do this:

```
aProductAvailabilityResult.ResultArrayCount := conditionList.Count;
for I := 0 to conditionList.Count - 1 do
begin
  aProductAvailabilityResult[I] := conditionList[I];
end;
```

You might want to consider adding a method to copy strings from a source `TStrings`:

```
type
  ProductAvailabilityResult = class(TRemotable)
  private
    ...
  public
    procedure AssignStrings(AStrings: TStrings);
    ...
  end;

procedure ProductAvailabilityResult.AssignStrings(AStrings: TStrings);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(FResultArray, AStrings.Count);
  for I := 0 to AStrings.Count - 1 do
    FResultArray[I] := AStrings[I];
end;
```

```
aProductAvailabilityResult.AssignStrings(conditionList);
```

Comment: Thanks this was also very helpful.